# Context Cannot be Resolved to a variable using gps

Tags: android

i am trying to show the address using gps location. 
error: context cannot be resolved to a variable

```
Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context,Locale.getDefault());
                    Address address;
                    String result = null;
                    List<Address> list = geocoder.getFromLocation(latitude, longitude, 1);
                    address = list.get(0);
                    result = address.getAddressLine(0) + ", " + address.getLocality();
```

Comment: In what line does this error happen? Is this a compile or runtime error? If it is a compile error, see the answer below, you need to declare the variable.

Answer (score 1):

you didn't have initialized context that's why this error is throwing.